# How to search by id in Mockable.io?

Tags: javascript, rest, web, service

I created a mock service using mockable.io.

For example:

Putting this in the url works:

> ```
> http://demo#####.mockable.io/items
> ```

But if I filter it with:

> ```
> http://demo#####.mockable.io/items?pid=5
> ```

It doesn't work as it should, it shows all the data instead of filtering them.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Mockable is in beta and I suspect they haven't sorted all the kinks out yet, I have the same problem when using it. An alternative is [Sandbox](http://getsandbox.com) - you can script mock service behaviour and can handle query parameters any way you like (disclaimer: I'm a founder)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your scenario and it works in my space.
Maybe you inverted the responses between the 2 mocks ?

You should send a support request to the mockable.io team. They are very active and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using filter.
Example: `/blogs?filter=blog1`

Documentation link: https://www.mockapi.io/docs

**SEARCHING & FILTERING**
Add query params to GET request:

```
/blogs?search=blog1

/blogs?filter=blog1

/blogs?title=cool%20blog
```